# JavaScript: Try/Catch - what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I am wrapping my code into try/catch blocks and I decided to test it out to see how it works.
Below is a simple snippet of code that will generate a Syntax Error  - `trigge rHandler`

```
try{
    $(document).trigge rHandler('fbload');
}catch(e){
     alert(e);
}
```

However I'm not getting the alert! Instead the error is logged in the console as an Unhandled Syntax Error. I was expecting that any error that is generated inside the Try block will automatically be passed down into the Catch section where I can do anything I want with it? Why does this not appear to be working?

Comment: You can't handle syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try..catch` will catch exceptions which occur at runtime. But Syntax errors occur during parsing time itself. So, when the code

```
$(document).trigge rHandler('fbload');
```

is encountered, JavaScript tries to parse the expression. But it couldn't. So it is clueless and fails immediately with SyntaxError and that is why it is not caught by the `except` block.

Comment: ... if they do not occur during parsing with `eval` operator.

Comment: Is there any way to catch those types of exceptions also?

Comment: @^ time to invent a new browser!! :)

Comment: @user1775598 Yes, Firebug and Google Dev Tools perfectly catch those exceptions.

Comment: But I will never be able to see them as those exceptions stay with the client? E.g. there are use cases where a a syntax error could only happens for one particular user but not the other. So there would be no way to log this?

Comment: @user1775598 Unfortunately, no :(